# How to sync position, bookmarks and notes over iCloud on ePub books

Tags: icloud, books, epub

I recently bought several ePub books from the Humble Bundle and from Smashing Magazine, hoping that I would be able to side load them into iBooks and then use iCloud to sync position, bookmarks, highlights and notes. I read that this should be possible here: http://blog.robertsalsbury.com/2012/08/15/ibooks-annotation-epub-and-icloud-syncing/

However after downloading the same files on my 2 devices (an iPad mini and an iPhone) this is not working. Nothing is getting synced!

Has the feature been removed, or am I missing something?

By the way I do not, nor will I ever want to, plug in my devices to my Mac. iCloud all the way for me.

Edit: I am using the latest version of iOS (6.0.1) and the latest version of iBooks (3.0.2) on both devices, and am logged in to the same iCloud account. I have some purchased books in my library and they are syncing fine.

Comment: To help troubleshoot: are you running the latest iBooks (3.0.2) and the latest iOS (6.0.1) on both devices? Is the same iCloud account logged in under `Settings -> iTunes & App Stores` on both devices?

Comment: Hi Dan, yes I have added a comment about that, I am using the latest versions and logged in with the same account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working by signing out and signing in again in the iBookstore. It then asked me if I wanted to sync, I said yes, but it still didn't work, so I went to Settings and saw that the sync switches were off, and now it works. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

I am still seeing the sync behavior I blogged about with the current versions of everything. My only suggestion is to note that the info doesn't get pushed up to the cloud and sync'd until you close the book.

-Robert

Comment: Is this just an assumption or did you verify?

Answer (score 0):

For me non-iBookstore epubs(generated by calibre) themselves don't sync
If I add them them to iTunes collection and sync to devices after that then 
last reading position/bookmarts,etc -works

iPhone4/iPad3(6.0.1)/iPad1(5.1.1),all non-jailbroken